# How can I host a C program in Apache?

Tags: c++, c, apache, cgi

I have a C program that gets called with a system call in a Perl script. I was wondering: Is there is a way I can actually host the C program itself inside of Apache so it can be managed with the same rules Apache has set such as timeout and memory?

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried and what doesn't work?.

If it begins with:

```
printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"); /* Or whatever the content type is */
```

...and then produces some output, and it's in your cgi-bin, then it ought to work.

Comment: Oh, and make sure it's executable... But yeah, it's really not complex.

Comment: thanks, what about the command line parameters it takes?  rewriting the program is not really an option as the code is already compiled and i dont have the source.

Comment: In that case you need a wrapper of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for how to [write an Apache module](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925670). Those are limited by Apache settings, while for example a CGI might do anything. However, I think that Apache in fact can limit a CGIs memory usage, for instance.

*(Not necessarily a bad thing, but you wanted to limit things from within the Apache configuration?)*

Comment: Apache can't limit CGI memory usage. CGI run new process separated from Apache.

Comment: @dns, yes, but the process will inherit ulimits from its parent.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) protocol between your C program and Apache.  The fastcgi development kit has a simple to use C API.

Here is an example FastCGI C program from the documention:

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h" /* fcgi library; put it first*/

#include <stdlib.h>

int count;

void initialize(void)
{
  count=0;
}

void main(void)
{
/* Initialization. */  
  initialize();

/* Response loop. */
  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)   {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
           "\r\n"
           "<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>"
           "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>"
           "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
            ++count, getenv("SERVER_HOSTNAME"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Get a sample test working before trying to use FastCGI. One thing at a time... But yes, FastCGI is definitely a good idea.

Comment: A normal CGI program can be turned into a FastCGI program with very little changes.  The person asking the question has a C program wrapped in a perl script, so the C program should already be very close to being a CGI program.

Comment: does that C program output the full response? or does the Perl script that wraps it add HTTP headers?  If the Perl script is very simple it might be best to include it in your question.  Atleast add to the question that you don't have the source code for the C program.

Answer (score 2):

If you can turn your program into a library you could use [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline) to hook it straight into your perl code. This would let you replace your `system()` call with a normal perl function call. You might have to sort out some data marshalling issues but Inline::C is a lot easier to work with than XS.